# Get access to breeze entity in the breeze entity manager to subscribe to propertychanged

Tags: validation, breeze

I have to audit changes to an entity, and I see how to get all the values, but I can't figure out how to get the entity from the entity manager in order to subscribe to changes to it. Here is what I have tried.

```
  // assume tblMw is an order entity attached to an EntityManager.
    manager.metadataStore("tblMw").entityAspect.propertyChanged.subscribe(
    function (propertyChangedArgs) {
        // this code will be executed anytime a property value changes on the 'order' entity.
        var entity = propertyChangedArgs.entity; // Note: entity === order
        var propertyNameChanged = propertyChangedArgs.propertyName;
        var oldValue = propertyChangedArgs.oldValue;
        var newValue = propertyChangedArgs.newValue;

        if (!entity.entityAspect.validateProperty(propertyNameChanged)) {
            //Property is not valid. Inform the user if needed.
        }

    });
```

I can't access tblMw Directly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused as to what you are trying to do.
Are you trying to subscribe to propertyChanged for every entity of type "tblMw"?

If yes, you can't really do that.
What you could do is to subscribe your entityManager to entityChanged event and in the event method check for the type of the entity:

```
    em.entityChanged.subscribe(function(args) {
        if (args.entity.entityType.shortName == "tblMw")
        // Do something
    });
```

More info on this at http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityManager.html.

The drawback is that the event will fire for every change on every entity.

The other option is to subscribe each instance of the entity manually.

This option might not be possible in your case, since you stated that you "can't access tblMw Directly". Although, it's not clear to me what mean as you would have to have access to each entity instance in your entityManager.